# ruby How to read a file and write to another file while skipping lines

Tags: ruby, file

I have a .txt file that I want to copy part of it to another file.
Here is what the text look like :

```
1
00:00:00 :  
renovation with a fully

2
00:00:01 :  
assembled 38-foot long trec

3
00:00:03 :  
skeleton, the exhibit offers a

4
00:00:04 :  
modern approach to presentation

5
00:00:07 :  
of more than 700 fossils with

6
00:00:08 :  
the exhibit starting in the
```

I want the new .txt file to look like

```
00:00:00 :  renovation with a fully
00:00:01 :  assembled 38-foot long trec
00:00:03 :  skeleton, the exhibit offers a
00:00:04 :  modern approach to presentation
00:00:07 :  of more than 700 fossils with
00:00:08 :  the exhibit starting in the
```

How can I remove the line number and the empty line and concatenate the lines with 'good' information
How can I do that?

Comment: You're asking us to write the code for you? Or, did you write the code and didn't show it to us? See "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
and "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.open("output.txt", "w") do |file_to_write|
  File.open("input.txt").each do |line|
    if $. % 4 == 2
      file_to_write.write(line.chomp)
    end
    if $. % 4 == 3
      file_to_write.write(line)
    end
  end
end
```

Ruby has a special symbol which will give you the line number `$.` you can substitute that with `File.open(filename).each_with_index do |line, index|` and use index instead of `$.`. 
If you use an index you will need to add 1 to it, because it will start off at 0.

This code goes through your input file line-by-line. The lines starting from the second and third line and then each following line of interest is offset by 4. 
Once we find the first half write that line to our opened file without a new line, once we find the second half (second `if` statement) write that line with a line terminator to the file.

Comment: Tracking `index_for_first_half` seems unnecessary when you can do `$. % 4 == 2` and `$. % 4 == 3`, respectively. Also, why use `print` one on line and `write` on the other? They are equivalent in this case.

Comment: You are correct I will update my answer. I was under the assumption that print prints without a \n char to the file unlike write.

Answer (score 3):

They make it seem so hard...

Ruby's [`foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) has the ability to receive a line-separator as the second parameter:

```
foreach(name, sep=$/ [, getline_args, open_args]) {|line| block } → nil
```

If you pass `"\n\n"` Ruby will return multiple lines that are separated by a blank line. That makes it easy to read through a file, such as yours.

Using your input data saved to a file, and running this code from the same directory:

```
File.foreach('test.txt', "\n\n") { |chunk|
  puts "%s %s" % chunk.lines[1, 2].map(&:chomp)
}
```

results in this output to the screen:

```
00:00:00 : renovation with a fully
00:00:01 : assembled 38-foot long trec
00:00:03 : skeleton, the exhibit offers a
00:00:04 : modern approach to presentation
00:00:07 : of more than 700 fossils with
00:00:08 : the exhibit starting in the
```

The separator can be any string, depending on the input file, but knowing this makes it easy to read files in chunks of lines, not just line-by-line.

If you MUST have multiple spaces trailing the delimiting colon:

```
:  r
```

versus

```
: r
```

the format string can be massaged to `"%s%s"` or switch to:

```
chunk.lines[1, 2].map(&:chomp).join
```

Resulting in:

```
chunk.lines[1, 2].map(&:chomp).join # => "00:00:00 :  renovation with a fully"
```

or

```
'%s%s' % chunk.lines[1, 2].map(&:chomp) # => "00:00:00 :  renovation with a fully"
```

How to write to a second file as you're reading from the input is left as an exercise for you.

---

Here are some benchmark results for amazement:

```
require 'fruity'

test_file = <<EOT
1
00:00:00 :  
renovation with a fully
EOT

test_file.gsub(/\A\d+|\n/, '')               # => "00:00:00 :  renovation with a fully"
test_file.lines[1, 2].map(&:chomp).join      # => "00:00:00 :  renovation with a fully"
'%s%s' % test_file.lines[1, 2].map(&:chomp)  # => "00:00:00 :  renovation with a fully"

compare do
  cary { test_file.gsub(/\A\d+|\n/, '') }
  ttm1 { test_file.lines[1, 2].map(&:chomp).join }
  ttm2 { '%s%s' % test_file.lines[1, 2].map(&:chomp) }
end

# >> Running each test 4096 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> ttm1 is similar to ttm2
# >> ttm2 is faster than cary by 2x ± 0.1

__END__
1
00:00:00 :
renovation with a fully
```

Comment: A variant is `File.foreach(fname_in, "\n\n") { |chunk| puts chunk.gsub(/\A\d+|\n/, '') }`. mamesaye, see [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub). The regular expression reads, "match one or more digits (`\d+`) at the beginning of the string (`\A`) or (`|`) match a newline (`\n`). `gsub` converts those matched strings to empty strings (i.e., it returns a string with the matched strings removed). For example, when `chunk` equals `"1\n00:00:00 :  \nrenovation with a fully\n\n"`, `'1'` at the beginning of the string and the four newline characters are matched...

Comment: ...so `gsub` returns `"00:00:00 :  renovation with a fully"`.

Comment: Using `gsub` and a pattern will run more slowly. It's shifting from simple string manipulation to regular expressions. Depending on the particular run Fruity is telling me the `gsub` and pattern is up to 2x slower. I've seen this before and usually anchoring will help, but I think the alternate `|` is slowing it. Perhaps a more comprehensive pattern will help.

Comment: I added two lines to your `compare` block: `sub_delete { test_file.sub(/\A\d+/, '').delete("\n") }` and `substr_delete  { test_file[test_file.index("\n")..-1].delete("\n") }`. I ran it several times. The following is indicative of the average result: "substr_delete is similar to ttm1, ttm1 is similar to sub_delete, sub_delete is similar to ttm2, ttm2 is faster than cary by 2x ± 0.1".

Comment: Feel free to update my answer with the benchmark code and results. It's always good to see how the different methods and ways of doing things affect the speed. Regex don't have to be slower, but in this case, where there's numerous jumps into the engine and out, I think they'll run more slowly. What would run the fastest would be to preprocess out the line numbers using a pattern in one pass, then walk through and rebuild the lines.

Answer (score 1):

Let's construct the input file.<sup>1</sup>

```
fname_in  = 'in'
```

```
File.write fname_in, <<~BITTER_END
1
00:00:00 :  
renovation with a fully

2
00:00:01 :  
assembled 38-foot long trec

3
00:00:03 :  
skeleton, the exhibit offers a

4
00:00:04 :  
modern approach to presentation

5
00:00:07 :  
of more than 700 fossils with

6
00:00:08 :  
the exhibit starting in the
BITTER_END
  #=> 268
```

We can read this file four lines at a time and for each group of four lines write a single line to the output file, where the single line is constructed from the second and third lines of each group of four lines.

```
fname_out = 'out'

File.open(fname_out, 'w') do |f|
  File.foreach(fname_in, chomp: true).each_slice(4) {|_, line2, line3, _|
    f.puts line2 + line3}
end
```

Let's confirm the output file was constructed properly.

```
puts File.read(fname_out)
00:00:00 :  renovation with a fully
00:00:01 :  assembled 38-foot long trec
00:00:03 :  skeleton, the exhibit offers a
00:00:04 :  modern approach to presentation
00:00:07 :  of more than 700 fossils with
00:00:08 :  the exhibit starting in the
```

I've used the method [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) to read the input file line-by-line. (This should be your go-to method for reading text files line-by-line). You can see from `foreach`'s doc that the method has two forms, one with a block and one without. I have used the latter, which returns an enumerator, because I want to chain it to the method [Enumerable#each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice).

Let's see how these enumerators work.

```
enum1 = File.foreach(fname_in, chomp: true)
  #=> #<Enumerator: File:foreach("in", chomp: true)>
enum1.next #=> "1" 
enum1.next #=> "00:00:00 :  " 
enum1.next #=> "renovation with a fully" 
enum1.next #=> "" 
enum1.next #=> "2" 
...
```

The option `chomp: true` causes `foreach` to strip off the newline character at the end of each line. See [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next).

We next have:

```
enum2 = enum1.each_slice(4)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: File:foreach("in", chomp: true)
  #    >:each_slice(4)> 
enum2.next
  #=> ["1", "00:00:00 :  ", "renovation with a fully", ""] 
enum2.next
  #=> ["2", "00:00:01 :  ", "assembled 38-foot long trec", ""] 
...
```

Compare the return values for the calculations of `enum1` and `enum2`. You can see that `enum2` can be thought of as a *compound enumerator*.

Elements are now generated by `enum2` and passed to its block, and values are assigned to the four block variables<sup>2</sup>:

```
line1, line2, line3, line4 = enum2.next
  #=> ["1", "00:00:00 :  ", "renovation with a fully", ""] 
line1 #=> "1" 
line2 #=> "00:00:00 :  " 
line3 #=> "renovation with a fully" 
line4 #=> "" line1
```

This process of breaking the array returned by `enum2.next` into four pieces is called [Array Decomposion](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition). It is a powerful and useful tool that may become fairly complex.<sup>3</sup>

We may now perform the block calculation:

```
str = line2 + line3
  #=> "00:00:00 :  renovation with a fully"
```

and then `f.puts str` to write that line to the output file. See [IO#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-puts).

The remaining calculations, beginning with:

```
line1, line2, line3, line4 = enum2.next
  #=> ["2", "00:00:01 :  ", "assembled 38-foot long trec", ""]
```

are similar.

Note that I've replaced the block variables `line1` and `line4`  with an underscore (`'_'`, a valid local variable), mainly to tell the reader that those variables are not used in the block calculation. This is common practice. Sometimes you might instead see `|_line1, line2, line3, _line4|`, meaning the same thing.

Here's a second way to construct `fname_out`:

```
File.open(fname_out, 'w') do |f|
  File.foreach(fname_in, chomp: true) do |line|
    case line
    when /\A\d+\z/
      str = ''
    when ""
      f.puts str
    else
      str << line
    end
  end
end
```

Lastly, if the file is not-overly large we could simply *gulp* it into memory, using `File::read`, and then use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regular expression to pull out the relevant lines, which then need to be cleaned up by removing newline characters.

```
File.read(fname_in).
     scan(r).
     map { |s| s.delete("\n") }
```

where the regular expression is as follows:

```
r =
/
^         # match the beginning of a line
\d{2}:    # match two digits followed by a colon
.+?       # match one or more characters lazily
(?=\n\n)  # the match is to be followed by two newlines
/mx       # multiline and free-spacing regex definition modes
```

<sup>1. To confirm the file was written correctly execute `puts File.read(fname_in)`. See [IO::write](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-write) and [IO::read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-read). [IO](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html) class methods are often invoked on the class [File](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/File.html), as I have done. That is permissible because `File.superclass #=> IO`, so `File` inherits `IO`'s methods.</sup>

<sup>2. Before doing so we need to execute `enum2.rewind`. See [Enumerator#rewind](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind).</sup>

<sup>3. If, for example, we have `a, (b, (c, d)) = [1, [2, [3, 4]]]`, then `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` will respectively be set equal to `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`.</sup>